# Вывод JSON данных в Flask

Tags: python, json, flask

Нужно сделать вывод данных в JSON формате.
Есть код с `return`

```
# START RECORD
@app.route("/start_record", methods=['POST'])
def start_capture():
    global camera
    with camlock:
        if camera:
            return 'already recording ' + record_file
        camera = picamera.PiCamera()
        camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
        camera.start_preview()
        camera.start_recording(record_file)
return jsonify({'status' : 200, 'record' : 'recording', 'startTime' : st, 'file' : record_file}, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

При выполнении его, показывает ошибку

> 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: добавь в начало `app.debug = True`, дабы включить режим дебага и понять ошибку. Думаю, ты дальше сам поймешь, в чем ошибка.

Comment: @MichaelPak Вывод происходит в консоли?

Comment: Дружище, ну посмотри сам в [доке](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#debug-mode). Но вообще нет, он тебе в `HTTP Response` выкидывает `traceback`.

Comment: @MichaelPak да вот кроме 500 Internal Server Error я там ничего больше не вижу.

Comment: @MichaelPak попробуй просто также вывести такой json как у меня выше

Comment: Переменные `st`, `record_file` в функции никак не определены (или мне кажется?). jsonify импортирован?

Comment: @tutankhamun все переменные определены, jsonify импортирован.

Comment: Проблема явно с переменными. Сделайте вместо последней строки такую `return '%s %s' % (type(st), type(record_file))` и результат покажите тут.

Comment: @tutankhamun сейчас к сожалению нету возможности попробовать. Как она появится, я отпишусь.

Comment: Я тут еще раз подумал. Далеко не факт что дело в этих перменных, но проверить стоит. В действительности стОит воспользоваться советом от MichaelPak и запустить приложение с `app.debug = True`. Там будет виднее где ошибка

Comment: @tutankhamun опробую как появится возможность. Я вот только не понял куда он пишет ошибки?

Comment: В браузер отдается traceback (ошибка и стек вызовов)